# How to make autoplay of the Swiper slider start only after the slider enters viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js, autoplay

I'm using this code to initialize swiper slider.

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 0,
    parallax: true,
    autoplay: 5000,
    speed: 800,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
})
```

Since the slider is positioned inside the fourth section of the page and is visible only after the page is scrolled down, I would like to make the autoplay start only after the slider enters the viewport.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
   autoplay: {
    delay: 5000,
  },

});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) please explain why this code solves the problem. Look at [answer]

Comment: You haven’t explained how this solves the issue, and this doesn‘t solve the issue anyway.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of only autoplaying when the element is in the viewport.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're trying play on 4th slides:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 0,
    parallax: true,
    autoplay: 5000,
    speed: 800,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
    onSlideChangeStart: function(s){
      if (s.activeIndex === 3) {
          // do something here, 4th slide is active now and so on
          console.log('hi! Try to reach 4th slides');
          s.startAutoplay(); // calling autoplay on 4th slides.
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Intersection Observer API to make slider autoplay only after the slider enters viewport.

Here's an example:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
// Optional parameters
  autoplay: {
    delay: 3000,
  },
});

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  const firstEntry = entries[0];
  if (firstEntry.isIntersecting) {
    swiper.autoplay.start();
  } else {
    swiper.autoplay.stop();
  }
});

const swiperContainer = document.querySelector('.swiper-container');
observer.observe(swiperContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use something like jquery appear - https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear

```
$('mySwiperContainer').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
  // this element is now inside browser viewport
  var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 0,
    parallax: true,
    autoplay: 5000,
    speed: 800,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
  }) 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Object with `autoplay` parameters needs to be used, or just boolean `true` to enable with default settings to enable autoplay. Here is an example with `delay` (between transitions in ms) parameter:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
 autoplay: {
   delay: 5000,
 },
});
```

[Documentation reference here](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#autoplay)